# Wordpress export to Jekyll - cannot figure out index link to posts

Tags: jekyll

I used `WordPress to Jekyll Exporter` Wordpress export to Jekyll.

I have uploaded files to `mygithubname.Github.io` repository.

I put the following code on `index.md`.

```
## Welcome to {{ site.url }}

### Posts

<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This shows a nice list of posts by their name. However, the link that is generated is like  `https://mygithubname.github.io/?p=856` and it doesn't actually link to anything.

I believe that Jekyll post urls should have post name so why is it generating the `?p=856` url ?

The export generated post page variables are like following:

```
---
id: 247
title: Always remember to start Python Virtualenv
date: 2016-01-29T03:56:06+00:00
author: mygithubname
layout: post
guid: http://mygithubname.github.io/?p=247
permalink: /?p=247
categories:
  - django
  - Python
---
```

How do I get Jekyll to generate links that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting URLs like `/?p=247` is because your posts have [`permalink`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) defined in the [front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) in each of your markdown files.  If you delete the `permalink` attribute, you will allow `jekyll` to auto generate the URL for each post.

If you would like some code samples, here is a simple `jekyll` based website, [minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima), that shows what happens when you omit `permalink` from the front matter of markdown (i.e. `*.md`) files.

Here is a specific post example showing how `jekyll` assigns URLs to posts.

Source code of one post:  https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_posts/2016-05-19-super-short-article.md

Rendered post: 
https://jekyll.github.io/minima/misc/2016/05/19/super-short-article.html

Comment: I opened all post files in Notepad++ and did a find and replace of `permalink` with `[//]: # permalink` to comment out all permalinks and it is now using Jekyll generated links.

Comment: @curtisp thank you for sharing what you did. It will be helpful for others who are in the same situation as you question.